# Javascript function result not appearing in the page (local testing): How can I identify the issue?

Tags: javascript, html

***Preface:*** 
I apologize that this is a fairly rudimentary topic problem within Javascript and webpage coding, but I am new to all of this and I have been frustrated trying to find a solution for almost a week now. It's hard for me to troubleshoot this on my own without much experience, though, so I am turning to you guys with the hope that you guys can identify my mistake or point me in the right direction.

***Context:***

I am working on a project/exercise for my intro programming course, and in this project, I am trying to make a loan payment calculator using HTML and Javascript.

I am using a known 5.9% annual interest rate, an input field for the user to enter the initial/principal loan amount, and a dropdown to select from 3 pre-set loan length plans: 36, 48, and 60 months. The goal is for the user to be able to input their initial loan amount, select a length, and click the "Calculate" button and have a monthly payment calculated and *shown on screen*.

***Problem:***

The calculate() function runs fine and outputs the correct values in Chrome's debugging source tool when I use breakpoints to stop it on the 24th line ("return payment;"), in which I can see that it outputs the correct monthly payment answer ($151.88...) for an initial value of 5000 and a length of 36 months at a 5.9% annual interest rate (just as an example).

However, resuming the script results in no answer appearing on the page.

---

***What I have tried:***

I have tried moving the different steps of the script code around(Comments above code sections indicate my idea of the different steps and their purpose). For example, I have tried inserting the "insert/load the code into the page" step into the calculate() function instead of it being outside of its scope.

In the final line (inserting the answer into the page) I have tested using only the payment variable and the calculate() function as the answer, and also tried using

```
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML == calculate(payment);
```

though I am not confident this is even a valid thing to do.

I have also tried moving the greetingButton declaration, greetingButton getElementById locator, and the greetingButton addEventListener code at the end of the document, as well as numerous other potential methods and fixes found on the internet. This code has changed around so much since last week, and yet still nothing seems to work.

***HTML body section code:***

```
<body>

<h1><strong>Loan Payment Calculator</strong></h1>
<br>
<hr>
<br>
<div class="top">
  <form name="loaninformation">

    <p><strong>Amount of the loan:</strong></p>
    <p><input class="textbox" type="text" id="principal"></p>

    <table>
      <tr>
        <td><strong>Duration:</strong></td>
        <select type="text" id="duration" class="dropdown">
          <option selected="selected" type="number" value="36">36</option>
          <option  type="number" value="48">48</option>
          <option  type="number" value="60">60</option>
        </select>
    </table>
    <button id="calculate"><strong>Calculate</strong></button>
  </form>
</div>

<div class="bottom">

    <p id="result"></p>

</div>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="script.js">
</script>
</body>
```

***Javascript:*** (file in same folder, with name "script.js"; file is linked correctly)

```js
// declarations (global variables)

var payment;
var greetingButton;
greetingButton = document.getElementById("calculate");

// run setup script on page load

window.addEventListener('load',setup,false);

/* setup function (ran on page load) - When button is clicked, run calculate() function */


function setup() {
  greetingButton.addEventListener("click",calculate,false);
}

// compute (when setup function receives button click)

function calculate() {
  var p = document.getElementById("principal").value;
  var n = document.getElementById("duration").value;
  var r = 0.059/12;

  var eqpart1 = ((parseFloat(r))*Math.pow((1+parseFloat(r)),parseFloat(n)));
  var eqpart2 = Math.pow((1+parseFloat(r)),parseFloat(n))-1;
  var eqpart3 =  parseFloat(eqpart1) / (parseFloat(eqpart2));
  payment = parseFloat(p)*parseFloat(eqpart3);
  return payment;

}

//load result into the page

document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Monthly Payment = $" + payment;
```

I expect the result of the monthly payment calculation to appear on the actual page in google chrome once values are defined by the user and the  button is clicked, but instead ***clicking the "Calculate" button clears all values entered and nothing shows up in the result section*** (unless the button is clicked without entering any values, but that I can fix on my own - I just need to get the result to appear right now)

Comment: Returning a value from an event handler does not have any effect (well, not in this case anyway). It certainly won't change anything about the target element. You have to explicitly update the DOM from inside the event handler.

Comment: Basically replace that `return` statement with the last line you posted (*inside* the "click" handler).

Comment: @Pointy Sorry I need a little clarification on what you mean. The ```return``` statement should be cut out and replaced by the ```document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Monthly Payment = $" + payment;``` from the last line of code? If so, I'm a bit confused on what you refer to when you then say "inside the 'click' handler" because as far as I can see neither of those lines are inside "click" handlers. Should that line be moved from the bottom to inside the same function as the ```function setup() {
  greetingButton.addEventListener("click",calculate,false);
}``` line? Or vice versa?

Comment: That's why you have to **move** the line that updates the DOM to **inside** the event handler. It's not clear how you'd expect the returned `payment` value to be available to that last line of code; that code executes when the page first loads and never again. That's why it needs to be moved into the event handler function. To be clearer, it should be the last line of the `calcuate()` function (after you get rid of the useless `return` from `calculate()`).

Comment: @Pointy Thank you. I will try that out and see if that gets the value to post. I really appreciate the advice!